# Error in RFT - memoryCorruptionDetected

Tags: java, jvm, rft

In RFT 8.3 an error occurs:

```
09:22:09.077 0x1bbb00   j9prt.748    *   ** ASSERTION FAILED ** at common/j9memtag.c:145: ((memoryCorruptionDetected))
```

I tryed set jvm option -Xverify:none and -Xdump:heap, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: report it to IBM?

Comment: And wait 2 week?